# Java Selenium - how to add wait for element in stream?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, java-stream

How can an explicit wait time be added for `WebElement` in a stream of `WebElement`s?

```java
driver.findElements(By.xpath("thisIsXpath"))
.stream()
.map(WebElement::getText)
.map(String::trim)
.collect(Collectors.toList());
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `WebDriverWait` to fetch all of your elements from the start rather than waiting for the element somewhere inside the `stream`.

```
List<String> elementTexts = wait
                            .until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(By.xpath("...")))
                            .stream()
                            .map(WebElement::getText)
                            .map(String::trim)
                            .collect(Collectors.toList());
```

`wait.until()` will return values based on what `ExpectedCondition` is used. For example,

| Return | ExpectedCondition |
| --- | --- |
| List<WebElement> | wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfAllElementsLocatedBy(...)) |
| WebElement | wait.until(ExpectedConditions.visibilityOfElementLocated(...)) |
| Alert | wait.until(ExpectedConditions.alertIsPresent()) |